# Scipy won't recognize my BLAS path when installing

Tags: python, linux, numpy, scipy, blas

I want to install scipy on a machine where I am not root following the instruction I found on this [page](http://gunheeleo.blogspot.fr/2010/04/python-install-numpy-and-scipy-without.html) but I meeting a BLAS not found error despite the fact that BLAS is install and "properly defined".

So I started installing the last python release (2.7.6) in a custom directoty ~/Tools/Python) which works fine. I compile then BLAST and LAPACK (3..5.0) following the instruction on this [page](http://www.giammy.com/phd/blas-lapack-howto.html). The compilation works fine and I put the respective .a files in some custom folders also (~Tools/BLAS with blas_LINUX.a and ~/TOOLS/LAPACK with liblapack.a and libtmglib.a). I then define two environment variables BLAS and LAPACK poiting to the directory above where the .a files are.

I then install numpy (1.8.1) using

```
python setup.py install --prefix=~/TOOLS/Python
```

and update my PYTHONPATH accordingly. Numpy works fine. However when shifting to the install of scipy (0.13.3), I get the following error:

```
numpy.distutils.system_info.BlasNotFoundError:
Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
the BLAS environment variable.
```

I try various combinaisons like specifying BLAS just before the call to the setup function but still it doesn't work. However I don't understand as when I type

```
echo $BLAS
```

the BLAS path is outputed. So any idea of what went wrong?